# Selecting parent ID and value of radio button, inserting into a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have lots of rows and columns in a table.
When a radio button is selected, I need to get it's value and the id of its parent element.

I will then use these to update a textarea or a input field.

There will be a another button that will take the values from the text-area and sync it to the database.

I have it somewhat working for a single row, but once the radio buttons are clicked/updated the divs also gets updated.

```
$(function() {
  $("input:radio").click(function() {
    var selectedId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    var clicked = [];
    $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
    clicked.push(selectedId+":"+this.value);
    }); //checked
    $("#an\\.ret\\.sys\\.4\\.").val(clicked);
  });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/PYcH3/5/)

Any idea where I am going wrong?

So when the radio button A of 1st row is clicked -- the text area should have 100~12~9:00 and when radio button D of 2nd row is clicked -- the text area should have 100~12~9:00, 100~16~23:03.

Comment: what is not working here?

Comment: I want the id of the parent div to be retained. eg. when you click the radio button of the first row..it should populate in the text area, and when you click the 2nd,3rd etc row radio button it should add in the text area. Hope I am making sense

Comment: Bro. Check my answer. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(function() {
     $("input:radio").click(function() {
      //var selectedId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');//Remove from here
      var clicked = [];
      $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
         var selectedId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');// Add here
          clicked.push(selectedId+":"+this.value);
        }); //checked
       $("#an\\.ret\\.sys\\.4\\.").val(clicked);
      });
  });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amitfts/PYcH3/6/)

Comment: Thank you, Amit. It works. Perfect. Any chance that the last value should end with a comma. like this 100~12~9:02,100~16~23:02,101~13~5:03, instead of 100~12~9:02,100~16~23:02,101~13~5:03

Comment: Hi! Amit, we lost the values of the radio button.  We are getting 100~12~9,100~16~23,101~13~5, instead of 100~12~9:02,100~16~23:02,101~13~5:03,

Comment: @19eggs I have changed `str+=selectedId+":"+this.value+',';`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48902/discussion-between-amit-garg-and-19eggs)

Comment: Thanks Amit. I saw that. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(function() {
$("input:radio").click(function() {
var clicked = [];
$("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
clicked.push($(this).parent().parent().attr('id')+":"+this.value);
 });
      $("#an\\.ret\\.sys\\.4\\.").val(clicked);
});
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PYcH3/7/)**

Comment: Hi! thank you..it works. Any chance that the last value should end with a comma. like this 100~12~9:02,100~16~23:02,101~13~5:03, instead of 100~12~9:02,100~16~23:02,101~13~5:03

Answer (score 1):

This should help

```
$(function() {
$("input:radio").click(function() {
var clicked = [];
$("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function(index,ele) {
    clicked[index] = ($(ele).parent().parent().attr('id')+":"+ $(ele).val());
 }); //checked
      $("#an\\.ret\\.sys\\.4\\.").val(clicked + ",");
});
});
```

Comment: perfected it.. but never late than ever :)

Comment: Thank you Faiz. Yours is slightly different but works. I was thinking maybe I should have used .map instead...

Comment: i had 2 thoughts
1. memory
You could just remove the each function and make clicked[] as a global array. But this comes at the cost of global memory   .. 2. cpu cycles
The above solution takes more cpu cycles if you notice,since it has to iterate everytime checkbox to see if this is checked (say you have 100 nos), then you may start facing perf issues